# Sitecore: Add to here button not showing on placeholder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7

I've been working through Martina Welander's SitecoreMVC tutorials (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3Mwcphtz4w ) and run into an issue when I try to add new placeholders.

When my placeholder is called "content" the Page Editor shows a nice clickable block with the Add to here heading. But if I change the name to anything else the block disappears.

At first I thought it might be because I hadn't set up any placeholder settings for that key, but even after doing that the Page Editor doesn't show the placeholder zone.

Clearly there's a basic step I'm missing somewhere to add the key to a list or something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check that you have a placeholder settings item with the same name, and that the settings item has 'Editable' selected.

Also, in Page Editor, check that you have 'Designing' enabled, under the 'View->Enable' menu.

Comment: Looks like I might have needed to publish the placeholder settings. Are placeholder settings required for each placeholder key to show the Add to here box though, seems a bit of an overhead to create them for every key?

Comment: You will for Page Editor. With no settings items you can still assign components to placeholders just by name in the content editor.
If you have a lot of placeholders, then you may need to reassess your page design, and see if it can be done more generically with less placeholders.

Comment: A bit late, but an addition from http://stackoverflow.com/a/32629319/1921754: You can allow editing for all placeholders, by setting `WebEdit.PlaceholdersEditableWithoutSettings` to `true` in the `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config` file.